# VB.Net Cannot Delete/Kill file downloaded from FTP site

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I confess I'm pretty novice at this FTP stuff. I'm trying to download a file from an ftp site, extract data, then delete it. Here is the relevant code (I got the functions from some forum, but haven't been able to find it since):

```
Public Declare Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet.dll" (ByVal HINet As Integer) As Integer
Public Declare Function InternetOpen Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenA" (ByVal sAgent As String, ByVal lAccessType As Integer, ByVal sProxyName As String, ByVal sProxyBypass As String, ByVal lFlags As Integer) As Integer
Public Declare Function InternetConnect Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetConnectA" (ByVal hInternetSession As Integer, ByVal sServerName As String, ByVal nServerPort As Integer, ByVal sUsername As String, ByVal sPassword As String, ByVal lService As Integer, ByVal lFlags As Integer, ByVal lContext As Integer) As Integer
Public Declare Function FtpGetFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpGetFileA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Integer, ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, ByVal lpszNewFile As String, ByVal fFailIfExists As Boolean, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Integer, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwContext As Integer) As Boolean

Sub Main()
    INet = InternetOpen("MyFTP Control", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
    INetConn = InternetConnect(INet, "ftp.myftpsite.com", 0, "username", "password", 1, 0, 0)
    FtpGetFile(INetConn, "test.csv", "C:\temp.csv", True, 1, 0, 0)
    InternetCloseHandle(INetConn)
    InternetCloseHandle(INet)

    'do stuff with file

    Kill("C:\temp.csv")

End Sub
```

It downloads the file just fine, but I get the following error at the kill command: "Access to the path 'C:\temp.csv' is denied." Same error if I use System.IO.File.Delete (see code section at the end for the Exception Detail).

What's strange is that I can delete the file manually with no problem. Also, if I copy the file I can kill the copy, but still not the original. I don't believe it's a connection/releasing issue, because I also cannot kill files downloaded several days & several computer reboots ago. I know it's not a directory privileges issue because I can manually move the file to the desktop, but still cannot kill it via code.

I've found a handful of forum postings with the same problem, but no posted answers. Just to clarify, I'm not trying to delete the file from the ftp site, but the downloaded file on my machine.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008. Thanks in advance!

Exception Detail:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
  Message="Access to the path 'C:\temp.csv' is denied."
  Source="Microsoft.VisualBasic"
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.Kill(String PathName)    at Project1.Module1.Main()    at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: As the error message suggests, you don't have enough privileges to write to c:\, which is quite normal in modern versions of windows. try to make a new directory somewhere and write it there.

Comment: I should have clarified - I shortened the path to just C:\ to make it cleaner here. But I know that standard privileges are not the issue, because I can kill other (non-ftp source) files in the same directory.

Comment: Have you used "Try catch and finally" ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx

Comment: I've used it elsewhere, but I have no idea what I could put in the Catch or Finally sections to help delete the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an AppData folder the problem should go away. Your app is not automatically going to have ownership of all files in all folders.

```
 mUserFileDir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) & _
 YourFolderName & YourFileName
```

or `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` depending on what it is doing and for whom.

Also maybe check the file attributes and persmissions.  Might be something there.

Comment: have you looked at the permissions and attributes for the file after a fresh dl?

Comment: Ah! It's marked as read-only! I had no idea that would make it so I could manually delete it, but not with code. How strange. Thanks!

Comment: Hm... If the answer is in a comment, what's the best way to mark the answer?

Comment: I dod an edit to the answer to include the attribute...I was going to say that up front but forgot.